# scroll view not scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

im new to ios programming and im trying to add a segmented controller to a scrollview because the seg controler is too big for the screen with out the scroll view scrolling horizontally. im not sure why it isnt scrolling. i think im missing something small, but i cannot find it. anything helps! thank you!

my code in the viewDidLoad:

```
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
self.scrollView.addSubview(segControl)
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = false
self.scrollView.contentSize.height = segControl.frame.height
self.scrollView.contentSize.width = segControl.frame.width
```

Comment: What's the value of `segControl.frame.width`? Is it greater than `scrollView.frame.width`?

Comment: scrollView.contentSize should be greater than scrollview.frame to make it scroll.

Comment: yes im 99% sure it is. how can i make that happen if it isnt? or how can i check to see if it is?

Comment: @user3462448 even i have same problem, i am embedding segment control inside scrollview. Scrollview is not scrolling. Can you share your solution ?

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView` is pretty easy to work with: as long as its `contentSize` is larger than its own `frame.size`, it will let you scroll to unveil its subviews that are off its visible area.

Probably check the `segControl.frame.width` and the `scrollView.frame.width` values: the `segControl`'s width should be larger for the scroll view to scroll.

It's also worth checking if the `scrollView.frame` is correct and is not lying somewhere off than the screen: e.g. `scrollView.frame.origin.x + scrollView.frame.width` is less than the screen width.

Looking at the screenshot, the `scrollView.contentSize.width` should be over `320` (since it's taking the whole width of the simulator screen, which is an iPhone 5/5S in your case). Since you have specified that your content width outputs as `216`, looks like you are accessing the frames in the wrong callback, which is triggered when the values are not yet correctly set. I can suggest moving the

```
scrollView.contentSize.height = segControl.frame.height
scrollView.contentSize.width = segControl.frame.width
```

part to `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: i did, it is larger. i printed it, this is what came up in the debug area. scrollview frame width: 0.0 content size: 216.0

Comment: What about the `scrollView.frame` — is it ok and not off the screen by any chance?

Comment: i have the scrollview trailing and leading constraints equal to the superview. so i dont think so.

Comment: the content size is 216 but the answer to this equation scrollView.frame.origin.x + scrollView.frame.width is 300. what does this mean?

Comment: it scolls to the left, but i think thats just the bounce. it doesnt actually scroll to show more of the seg control.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of what you see when you launch it? I think this would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: i have some constraints set up. would that cause a problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another suggestion: try moving the part where you set the `contentSize` to `viewWillAppear`. The values of the `contentSize` and `scrollView.frame` that you've provided conflict with what we see in the screenshot, so I'd say you're trying to check them in the wrong place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112416/discussion-between-user3462448-and-alex-staravoitau).